# PHP Laravel route after installation

Tags: php, laravel, url, routes, backend

I installed new laravel project("Starter") and want to view the 'welcome' page by putting this URL.

http://localhost/starter/

The page ran fine when the route is the following.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

However, when I write any thing after the (/)...

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

And view it by URL:

http://localhost/starter/test

The page doesn't work and shows...

> ```
> 404
> Not Found
> ```

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to run `php artisan route:list` and show the output

Comment: Here `http://localhost/starter/test` where `/starter` come from? It would be `http://localhost/test`

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\Starter>php artisan route:list
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+------------+
| Domain | Method   | URI      | Name | Action  | Middleware |
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+------------+
|        | GET|HEAD | /        |      | Closure | web        |
|        | GET|HEAD | api/user |      | Closure | api        |
|        |          |          |      |         | auth:api   |
+--------+----------+----------+------+---------+------------+

Comment: maybe you need to use localhost/starter/public/test

Comment: I removed "public" path from URL

Comment: Thank you everyone I changed the browser and worked fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(s) in word (starter) in the URL, shoud be UpperCase (Starter) as the name of Laravel project